# How can i solve this ASP.NET DataList problem?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I'm trying to make a website on ASP.Net and i created database before. So, i wanted to list my object from database and i added a datalist tool to my form. Connection is okay but programme can't find DataList. I didn't change DataList's name, it is DataList1 but it can not be find. Can you help me?

```
public partial class AnaSayfa1 : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    SqlBaglantisi bgl = new SqlBaglantisi();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCommand komut = new SqlCommand("Select *from Kategoriler", bgl.baglanti());
        SqlDataReader oku = komut.ExecuteReader();

        DataList1.DataSource = oku;
        DataList1.DataBind();
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post some .aspx code of the DataList1 here for better understanding?

Comment: @ShubhadeepChattopadhyay i did it for the master page, so there is not another codes for DataList1

Comment: OK then can you please post that inline code for DataList1 here?

Comment: @ShubhadeepChattopadhyay
 <ItemTemplate>
                     <strong>
                     <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("KategoriAd") %>'></asp:Label>
                     </strong>
                 </ItemTemplate>

Comment: Is the datalist present in the masterpage.designer file?

Comment: @ShubhadeepChattopadhyay yes.